# background colors in terminal emulators

Tags: terminal, colors, gnome-terminator

I am experiencing strange terminal behavior on two different machines with two different `terminator` versions:

The program that creates these colourings is `grc` (generic colouriser). `grc` is written in python and uses simple config files where coloring can be configured. The problematic line is configured by:

```
regexp=[    ](\/(boot|dev|etc|home|lost\+found|mnt|opt|proc|root|run|srv|sys|tmp|usr|var)\/\s+h?$)
colours=unchanged, on_blue
```

I have made two screenshots and combined them for comparisson (attached below)

Basically, when text has background color, terminal1 colors also the spaces between words. terminal2 leaves spaces between words black.

I would like behavior of terminal1 (left)

Any way to change this ?

[image]

Comment: without knowing what program you're using in the terminal, and what terminal description, it's too vague to answer.

Comment: @Thomas Dickey - thanks, I have edited my question and added more details.

Comment: Output of `echo $TERM` for each, please. If they're the same the next place to look is tab settings. Do you get the same effect (one "right" and one "wrong") after running `reset` in each terminal?

Comment: @roaima -  `echo $TERM` says `xterm-256color` on both. And running `reset` does not change anything.

Comment: @roaima - what do you mean by tab settings ?

Comment: I guess that one version doesn't include the `hpa` capability in its terminfo entry (and that program is badly kludging its way around it), or it implements it incorrectly. If you try the following in the terminal from the left, will it also make the background of the space  between the `foo` and the `bar` red? `printf '\033[41mfoo'; tput hpa 33; printf 'bar\033[m\n'`

Comment: Also, what does `stty | grep -o tab3` say?

Comment: @mosvy thank you very much - I've been out enjoying watching the fireworks in town (UK tradition for [5th November](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_Fawkes_Night)) - you've seen exactly where I was heading with the tabs question.

Comment: @roaima looks I haven't read the Q carefully; if the OP likes the one on the left, then simply `stty -tabs` or `stty tab3` will do.

Comment: @mosvy - the space between `foo` and `bar` is not colored. `stty -tabs` prints nothing. when I set `stty tab3`, it makes not difference.

Comment: Do you mean that setting `stty -tabs` or `stty tab3` (they're the same thing) in the _right_ terminal does not cause the space between the words to be colored? Please run that program inside `script(1)` and post the `typescript` file somewhere.

Comment: I see ([this](https://github.com/garabik/grc)).  If you were running the program in screen or tmux, that could be related to the *background color erase* feature.  Otherwise, perhaps a bug in [terminator](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/terminator).  **grc** itself is *hardcoded*, so `TERM` is irrelevant.  For what it's worth, it doesn't do clearing by itself.